# Zipping a file without copying its directory into the archive using Perl with IO::Compress::Zip

Tags: perl, zip

I am assigned the task of changing some Perl code that creates a *zip* archive to make it compatible with *zip64* so that it can create archives more than 4 GB in size or have more than 64K members.

The old code was using [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Zip) module which is limited to zip and doesn't include the zip64 extension. So now I am playing around with the [`IO::Compress::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Compress::Zip) module which supports zip64.

I am trying to compress two files on my desktop and place the new archive on my desktop.
Everything is working fine, but the files are not placed in the root of my archive, their whole directory is created inside the archive.

For example, I have two files in my desktop: `file1` and `file2` and I use the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError) ; 

my $file = $ENV{"HOME"}."/Desktop/file1";
my $file2 = $ENV{"HOME"}."/Desktop/file2";

my $s = zip [ $file1, $file2 ] => $ENV{"HOME"}."/Desktop/new_.zip" , zip64 => 1 
        or die "zip failed: $ZipError \n";
```

When I go and check my archive I find the following directory

```
"home"-> "mohamad" -> "Desktop"
```

and inside this directory I find my files.

How can I copy my files directly to the root of the archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Zip), [`IO::Compress::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Compress::Zip) will include the directories that you specify in the files to be archived. Instead of using `$ENV{"HOME"}."/Desktop/` everywhere you should just

```
chdir "$ENV{HOME}/Desktop"
```

and then specify the bare filenames that you want to save. It solves your problem as well as making the code a lot tidier.

It looks like this. Note that I have used `autodie` to avoid having to explicitly check whether the `chdir` has succeeded. Also, on my Windows 7 system the correct environment variable is `USERPROFILE` but I imagine you are running XP or some other variant.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError);

chdir "$ENV{HOME}/Desktop";

my $file1 =  'file1';
my $file2 =  'file2';

my $s = zip [ $file1, $file2 ] => 'new_.zip', Zip64 => 1 
        or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

---

**Update**

As an alternative you can use the `FilterName` callback to modify the name stored in the zip file. To remove the path entirely is straightforward and looks like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Compress::Zip qw(zip $ZipError);

my $file1 =  "$ENV{HOME}/Desktop/file1";
my $file2 =  "$ENV{HOME}/Desktop/file2";

my $s = zip [ $file1, $file2 ] => "$ENV{USERPROFILE}/Desktop/new_.zip",
    FilterName => sub { s<.*[/\\]><> },
    Zip64 => 1,
        or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

Comment: Thank you !, do you know if there is a way to mimic  the `addFile($name, $new_name)` functionality in `Archive::Zip`, or if there is a way to rename archive members after compressing ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi: All I know about is the `FilterName` callback which allows you to specify a subroutine that will modify the name that is stored in the zip file. I have added to my answer to explain.

Comment: is `FilterName` one of the options that can be passed to  zip ? I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: Yes it is - search for FilterName in http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.064/lib/IO/Compress/Zip.pm

Comment: Is there a method for removing only the path to the working directory and leave subfolder paths? s|$cwd|| doesn't seem to quite do it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist in `IO::Compress::Zip`, but if it acts like other compression utilities/libraries, you need to cd to `$ENV{"HOME"}."/Desktop/` and then compress just `["file1", "file2"]`

Comment: That my work around for now, I am using `chdir` before I compress. But it seems a bit stupid